# Htaccess blog slug Rewrite does not work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to use following method to get the url of the page 
www.mysite.com/blog/this-an-article 
htaccess code:

```
  RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ blog/page.php?slug=$1  [NC,L]
```

So this code does not work and I get 404 error... page not found.
I have got a subfolder called: blog and inside it - index.php and page.php.
Can you help me please?
Thank you

Comment: Define "does not work". What does it do and what do you expect it to do? Add more details to your question until it's about three times as long as it is now.

Comment: I get 404 page error ... page not found

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/page.php?slug=$1  [NC,PT,L]

Try with the first slash "/" and look at the flag "PT"

Comment: Im sorry:
RewriteRule ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/page.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]

use the first slash "/" in both, in the regular expression and in the destination url

Comment: It is still the same... page not found. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/page.php?slug=$1 [NC,PT,L]

If you execute /blog/page.php?slug=something-real it works?